# How to filter Trello activity for a given member

Tags: trello

I simply want to see my own activity for a given day (yesterday most of the time).

Since the Trello app doesn't seem to have this, I was looking into the Trello API, so I could build some script to pull this off when needed.

It seems like [GET /1/boards/[board_id]/actions](https://trello.com/docs/api/board/index.html#get-1-boards-board-id-actions) should be able to give me this, but I can not find the options to filter by member id.

Answer (score 4):

[image]Currently Trello doesn't provide filter activity feature but **if you simply want to see your activity for yesterday or certain day**, you can simple go to your profile and you will see all your activities there order by the date. So you can easily scroll for certain date or yesterday. You can apply this approach for the other members as well.
Good luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can see your Trello activity by following the URL

```
https://api.trello.com/1/members/ {username} /actions?key= {app key} &token= {token}
```

The actions are presented as a reverse-chronological list within a JSON object (having a JSON-formatting browser extension definitely helps).

The process of getting the app key and a token is described in [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/80852).

See the [documentaton of /members/id/actions/ method](https://trello.com/docs/api/member/index.html#get-1-members-idmember-or-username-actions) for the syntax of parameters "since" and "before", which allow the results to be restricted to a particular day.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Trello does have this feature now.

Open the menu panel on the right and left-click on a member. There you'll see an option called 'View Member's Board Activity'.

[image: Trello view board activity]

Answer (score 0):

**Since 2019**, you can see the member's board activity in the following way:

1. Open the board.
2. Click on the member's image in the top bar.
3. Click on *View Member's Board Activity*.

Please refer to the attached screenshot for a more visual explanation.

Hope it helps!

Cheers,
Guido

[image: screenshot]